# Send JSON data to REST API with sub payloads

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I am trying to send JSON data to a REST API using my C# application

The JSON data should be like that:

```
{
    'agent': {
        'name': 'AgentHere',
        'version': 1
    },
    'username': 'Auth',
    'password': 'Auth'
}
```

So, as you can see... `agent` have sub payloads which are `name` and `version`

I am calling the REST API using RestSharp like that:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://example.com");
            // client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);

    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddParameter(
        "{'agent': { 'name': 'AgentHere', 'version': 1 }, 'username': 'Auth', 'password': 'Auth' }"
    );

    // easily add HTTP Headers
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    // execute the request
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    var content = response.Content; // raw content as string
```

But I get the errors `The best overloaded method match for 'RestSharp.RestRequest.AddParameter(RestSharp.Parameter)' has some invalid arguments` and `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'RestSharp.Parameter'` on this line:

```
request.AddParameter(
            "{'agent': { 'name': 'AgentHere', 'version': 1 }, 'username': 'Auth', 'password': 'Auth' }"
        );
```

I am unable to make the sub payload

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that data is meant for the request body. Use the appropriate `AddParameter` overload.

```
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

var contentType = "application/json";
var bodyData = "{\"agent\": { \"name\": \"AgentHere\", \"version\": 1 }, \"username\": \"Auth\", \"password\": \"Auth\" }";

request.AddParameter(contentType, bodyData, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

To avoid constructing the JSON manually, which can lead to errors, use the `AddJsonBody()` with an object representing the data to serialize

```
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
var data =  new {
    agent = new {
        name = "AgentHere",
        version = 1 
    }, 
    username = "Auth", 
    password = "Auth" 
};
//Serializes obj to JSON format and adds it to the request body.
request.AddJsonBody(data);
```